# Как можно считать n-мерный массив из файла?

Tags: python, массивы, файлы, txt

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На выходе должно быть так:

```
n1 = [[1, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 2]]
n2 = [[2, 3 ,3], [4, 2, 1], [1, 3, 2]]
...
```

Возможно ли так?

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы переменные n1, n2 создавались динамически в коде? Можно, но не нужно. Нужно работать с контейнерами (список, словарь), а не переменными. А чтобы что-то предложить взамен нам нужно понимать как вы используете эти данные.

Comment: Прочитать строку, преобразовать через `ast.literal_eval`

Answer (score 1):

В вашем вопросе мало конкретики. Как я понял, вам нужно это

```py
import numpy as np

# Чтение файла и преобразование в массив NumPy
matrix = np.genfromtxt('matrix.txt', delimiter=' ')

# Преобразование типа данных
matrix = matrix.astype(int)

# Определение количества строк и столбцов в матрице
num_rows, num_cols = matrix.shape

# Обработка всех элементов матрицы
for i in range(num_rows):
    for j in range(num_cols):
        element = matrix[i, j]
        print(element)
```